# I need the date calculation in Python => Midnight from the previous day to the current time of day

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need a date calculation in Python => Midnight from the previous day to the current time of day.

Sample:

```
CURRENT DATE        TRANSFORMATION
28/07/2017 17:00 => 26/07/2017 23:59:59 
26/07/2017 16:00 => 24/07/2017 23:59:59
```

Attempted the code and it does not work.

Code

```
import datetime
days_ago = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
```

Comment: This is not Santa Claus' wish list nor "write me code" service. You must work on this yourself and come with real problems with **your code**

Comment: Welcome to SO, make sure you have taken the [tour], seen [ask] and if you post some code make it [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You started well. Then just change hour minute and second:

```
import datetime
days_ago = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
days_ago = days_ago.replace(second=59, minute=59, hour=23)
```

But from your examples it might be `days=-2`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just counting seconds in the concerned day only ?

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now() # or any other date
s = now.hour * 3600 + now.minute * 60 + now.second
print(s) => 38801 at this time
```

Eventually you may have issues with timezones depending on the application you want to do with it.